# How to check checkbox when testing if it has defaultChecked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Here is a demo of what I'm trying to achieve: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/8y2kormlx9)

The thing is, I see that I can change the value and make the checkbox checked if there is no defaultChecked property, but it's legacy code and I can't take it out easily, I need that property there.

**I need:** e.currentTarget.checked to come true in the testing environment, it comes false. IT does come true when I remove defaultChecked false, but I need it there.

**I use** react-testing-library with jest.

**And code from demo here:**

```
export class OptionCheckbox extends React.Component {
  changeHandler = e => {
    console.log("onchange triggered", e.currentTarget.checked);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.changeHandler}
          defaultChecked={false}
          id="test"
          name="test"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        <label htmlFor="test">
          <span />
          Test
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// TEST

test("Example test of change event", () => {
  const component = renderIntoDocument(<OptionCheckbox />);

  component.getByLabelText("Test").setAttribute("checked", "");

  fireEvent.change(component.getByLabelText("Test"));

  component.unmount();
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear. PLease be specific on the point

Comment: The point, it I should be able to check the checkbox as I specified in the question. To be even more clear,    
 console.log("onchange triggered", e.currentTarget.checked); // should give true after setting checked attribute

Comment: still not clear of why you want to achieve this but probably this line 
 `component.getByLabelText("Test").setAttribute("checked", "");` is making your output to come `false`

Comment: What do you mean by not clear? I need  to make the checkbox checked in a testing environment. What reason for that could be... And no, it doesn't that's how you check the checkbox. If you're curious, you can remove defaultChecked property and see that it works, my question was how to make it work without removing that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to access property directly, rather than through setAttribute method.This will do what I wanted and get me e.currentTarget.checked === true in the onchange handler.

**UPDATE**: This was for the old version of the library, around 3.x.y. In the new version I don't do what described below, and just use fireEvent.click;

```
/* SOLUTION */

  component.getByLabelText("Test").checked = true;
  fireEvent.change(component.getByLabelText("Test"));
/* SOLUTION */
```